# Why won't textFieldTableCells display text?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am currently making a project in JavaFX, where my current goal is to create a table of TextFieldTableCells. A Team object carries a series of objects, and the program displays all of the values it needs to when the TextFieldTableCells are not added. On the other hand, if all of the added values are set to null, the table will contain textFields which work just fine. The problem lies when both are combined together, which causes many errors, which happen when the JavaFX class containing the table is initialized. Why doesn't this work?

```
    @FXML
    TableView table;
    @FXML
    TableColumn <Team, String> teamName = new TableColumn<>("Team Name:");
    @FXML
    TableColumn <Team, String> offRtg = new TableColumn<>("Offensive Ratings:");
    @FXML
    TableColumn <Team, String> defRtg = new TableColumn<>("Defensive Ratings");
    String[] teamNames = new String[20];
    String[] offRtgs = new String[20];
    String[] defRtgs = new String[20];
    int[] finalOffRtgs = new int[20];
    int[] finalDefRtgs = new int[20];
    Team[] teams = new Team[20];
    ObservableList<Team> allTeams;
    @FXML
    protected void toMain() {
        Driver.back();
    }
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        Driver.database.load();
        teams = Driver.database.getTeams();
        allTeams = FXCollections.observableArrayList(teams);
        teamName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("teamName"));
        teamName.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
        offRtg.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("offRtg"));
        offRtg.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
        defRtg.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("defRtg"));
        defRtg.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
        table.setEditable(true);
        teamName.setEditable(true);
        offRtg.setEditable(true);
        defRtg.setEditable(true);
        teamName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        offRtg.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        defRtg.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            table.getItems().add(allTeams.get(x));

        }

    }
}
```

All TableColumns are inside the table object, this has been done in SceneBuilder which is why it doesn't show up in this class. Again, the table works with TextFields or with the values, but not both. I've never encountered this problem before.
This is the fxml class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="780.0" prefWidth="661.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.football_sim.EditTeams">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="282.0" layoutY="754.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toMain" text="Return to Main" />
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="661.0" text="Edit Teams" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font size="41.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="91.0" prefHeight="524.0" prefWidth="451.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="teamName" maxWidth="150.0" minWidth="150.0" prefWidth="150.0" sortable="false" text="Team Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="offRtg" maxWidth="150.0" minWidth="150.0" prefWidth="150.0" sortable="false" text="OffRtg" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="defRtg" maxWidth="150.0" minWidth="150.0" prefWidth="150.0" sortable="false" text="DefRtg" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It's difficult to see what is going on with db.  try to add hardcoded items. And since this app was made in scenebuilder you may add  fxml file as well

Comment: @GiovanniContreras it has been added.

Comment: [mcve] please.. make sure to read, understand that help page and act accordingly!

Comment: ahh .. you __must not__ instantiate fields that are injected via fxmlLoader

Comment: @kleopatra is right you are making new objects ( 3 tablecolumns)